# array objects loading but not connecting to cell

Tags: ios, arrays, tableview

I'm passing an array of favorites -- from a details view -- to (what should be) a table view displaying the favorites individually.
The first array [in the first view] is okay:

```
Array found. Contents: (
    "\U5df4",
    "\U5df4",
    "\U82ad\U8305//\U5df4\U8305",
    "\U5df4\U5bb6",
    "\U7b06\U7bd3\U513f",
    "\U5df4",
    "\U5df4",
    "\U5df4",
    "\U5df4",
    "\U5df4",
    "\U5df4\U5bb6",
    "\U5df4",
    "\U5df4",
    "\U5df4"
)
Number of items in my array is: 15
```

and printing it [from the second array in the second view]:

```
Printing description of self->FavsTwo:
<__NSCFArray 0x1f9644a0>(
巴,
巴,
芭茅//巴茅,
巴家,
笆篓儿,
巴,
巴,
巴,
巴,
巴,
巴家,
巴,
巴,
巴,
巴家
)
```

is also cool...

The first break i get is here:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [FavsTwo count];
}
```

and then all these errors:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/UITableView.m:6235
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
***
```

my cell looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSString *cellValue = [self.FavsTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    return cell;


}
```

trying to convert objects to strings -- not really sure where it's failing

cheers

Comment: @Himanshu Joshi both work below to load the table but i'm still crashing at number of rows - return [FavsTwo count]; *FIRST* clicking continue in the debug gets it to load....

Comment: Did you log `[FavsTwo count];`?

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi seems like it was the capitalization error mentioned below that threw it off! thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing self in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return [self.FavsTwo count];
}
```

The [`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW5) may return `nil` if it can not deque a cell.

You need to check if the cell is `nil`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(!cell) {
        cell = [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
    }    

    NSString *cellValue = [self.FavsTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
```

If you have used [`registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW93) or [`registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW76).The you need to get the cell with [`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW92):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *cellValue = [self.FavsTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: this works to load the table but I'm still crashing at number of rows - return [FavsTwo count]; *FIRST* clicking continue in the debug gets it to load....

Comment: @user3306356 updated my answer, also in Objectics-C is not is not common to start any variable with a capitol, so `self.FavsTwo` should be `self.favsTwo`.

Comment: must have the the capitalization that threw it ... working now!

Answer (score 2):

cellForRowAtIndexPath return nil, if can not `ReusableCell`,  you should create a  cell with the`CellIdentifier`

try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSString *cellValue = [self.FavsTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: this works to load the table but I'm still crashing at number of rows - return [FavsTwo count]; *FIRST* clicking continue in the debug gets it to load....

Comment: @user3306356 can you list the crash info about `return [FavsTwo count]`

Comment: must have been rckoenes's comment about the capitalization that threw it off...thanks for your help though!

Comment: @user3306356  the capitalization will not cause crash,  adding `self.` to  `FavsTwo` should be the solution.